# I wasn't able to find a good resource for Bipartite state and Bell's theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations, bells-inequality

Our professor used tensor product to explain bipartite operator and states and then he used the new operator and state to explain Bell theorem.  I wasn't able to find a good resource or reference for it. Can you help me to find a good resource for these topics?

Comment: Bell states see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state), their definitions

Comment: See also the article [Spectral decomposition of Bell’s operators for qubits](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0103068.pdf)